# python takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, oop

I have a class that calls upon another class to use it's function

```
main.py
--------------------
class MyClass():

    def main(self, arg):
        from lib.otherclass import OtherClass
        otherClass = OtherClass() 

        result = otherClass.prepare.importImage(image)


myClass = MyClass()
final = myClass(image)
```

I get this error

```
importImage() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is what the other class looks like:

```
class OtherClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.prepare = Prepare()

class Prepare():

    def importImage(image):
        blah blah blah
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `importImage` is missing a `self` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either:

```
class Prepare():

    def importImage(self, image):
```

or:

```
class Prepare():

    @staticmethod
    def importImage(image):
```

see [python takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109306/python-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given/) and [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)